# How to use ternary operator in cshtml page. (Razor View Engine)

Tags: model-view-controller

I am working with .cshtml pages.
I want to show some html conditionally by getting value from Session variable.
If i am using if else condition in cshtml pages it works, but i want to replace it with ternary operator.

**Here is working Code: -**

```
    @if (HttpContext.Current.Session["RequestCount"] != null)
     {
       if (HttpContext.Current.Session["RequestCount"].ToString() != "0")
          {
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link ripple" href="@Url.Action("Images", "Admin")"> <i class="icon-bell-ring" style="position:relative"><em>@HttpContext.Current.Session["RequestCount"].ToString() </em></i><span>Images Request</span> </a> </li> 
          }
       else
          {
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link ripple" href="@Url.Action("Images", "Admin")"> <i class="icon-bell-ring"></i> <span>Images Request</span> </a> </li>
          }
     }
```

**Trying to use ternary operator : -**

```
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link ripple" href="@Url.Action("Images","Admin")"> <i class="icon-bell-ring" style="position:relative">@HttpContext.Current.Session["RequestCount"].ToString) != "0" ?<em>@HttpContext.Current.Session["RequestCount"].ToString(): &nbsp; </em></i><span>Images Request</span> </a> </li>
```

Comment: First, what error are you getting?  Second, It looks like you have an open `<em>` tag in one branch of the ternary and the close in the second branch.  Try formatting that line a little better and it might become obvious why it isn't working.  Also, parenthesis might make it easier to indicate where the end of the ternary is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks @Becuzz, error is that it is not working conditionally, it shows both html. http://prntscr.com/kp3g0j

Comment: I want to hide the red bubble if session has value == "0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the ternary operator, you need to do a couple of things.

1. Surround the whole thing with parenthesis.  As you have it written, the `?` gets interpreted as text, not an operator.  So start with something like this:

   `@(myCondition ? "a" : "b")`
2. Don't put opening tags inside the operator (unless you put the close one in as well).  So move the `em` tags outside like this.

   `<em>@(/* ternary operator here */)</em>`
3. Finally, make sure the return type is the same for both branches.  In your example you are trying to return a regular string in one part (the `HttpContext` bit) and the second you are trying to return a non-breaking space (I assume you don't want the literal text `&nbsp;` output to the page).  So wrap them both in `HtmlString`s.

So when it's all put together you get something like this (below is a sample Razor page in a .Net Core web app I tried this on, adapt to your needs):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html
@{
    bool isTrue = false;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <em>@(isTrue ? new HtmlString("hi") : new HtmlString("&nbsp;")) </em>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```